# Brunch.io - require conflict

Tags: coffeescript, brunch

I'm using coffeescript and brunch.io to compile my project in a single `app.js` file which is great !!!!

- in *main project* I have `tools = require 'utils/tools'`
- in *my library* I also have a utils directory (different then the one from *main project* with an tools file. So in the library code: `tools = require'utils/tools'`

Then in a browser I'm sourcing both *main project* and *my library*.

The big problem is that brunch imports only the first `utils/tools` and not the second one (because everything is global as I could see and utils/tools was already set, I guess).

How can I resolve this ? I already got two ideas but I think I can find something better

- 1 Solution: rename the folder (eg: utils2/)
- 2 Solution: rename the file (eg: utils/tools2.coffee)

Any better idea ? Is it possible to define a domain name or a namespace for `require` ?

Best regards

*PS: it's `require` from brunch.io not nodeJS :P*

Comment: Why did you downgrade this question ?

Comment: there are a lot of implementations of require. So it may depend of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

es128 answer: https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/854

**SOLUTION**

Change your module config to adds namespacing to your component. You could write a custom wrapper, but probably the cleanest way is something like

```
modules:
  nameCleaner: (path) ->
    "myComponentName/#{path.replace(/^app\//, '')}"
```

or this more reusable version that grabs the name from package.json

````
{name} = require './package'

modules:
  nameCleaner: (path) ->
    path.replace /^app/, name```
````